# parse of "stopped"

Tags: parsing

Where are you? (on the phone)
**(1)** *I'm stopped by police*.
**(2)** *I'm stopped at a red light*.

(1):
"Am stopped" is a verb.
"Stopped" is a past participle.

(2):
"Am" is a verb.
"Stopped" is a subject complement.
"Stopped" is an adjective.

Is my parse correct? If not, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all five parts of your parse are correct.

It's worth noting that your first sentence has the wrong tense for the context. The present simple has the function of describing *things that happen regularly*, so "I'm stopped by police" means "I am *regularly* stopped by the police." This doesn't make sense as an answer to the question, "Where are you?" because you're describing your current situation, not something that happens regularly. Present perfect works:

> I've been stopped by the police.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You have to say something like:

> **The police stopped me.**

or

> **I got stopped by the police.**

(2) This sentence is perfectly fine:

> **I'm stopped at a red light.**

Without the contraction, it's"

I am stopped at a red light.

*am* is the verb and **stopped** is an *adjective*.

To use it as a verb, you can say:

> **I stopped at a red light.**

Here's [something to read](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stop_1) for more information.

Comment: What do you mean, "It needs a subject"? The pronoun "I" is the subject (or If you mean "agent" rather than "subject", "police" is the agent). The lack of subject (or agent) isn't the problem. It's the tense. "I've been stopped by police" has the same subject (and agent), but is correct for the context.

Comment: -1 The word "stopped" is **not** an adjective here. It is a verb form, specifically a past participle, and "am" is serving as an **auxiliary verb**.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. In "I am stopped at a red light", the word "stopped" ***is*** an adjective. Why you got downvoted and Gotube, who agrees with you, didn't is a mystery to me! Best ask @David !